# If I disable the integrated graphics on a laptop with an eGPU connected, will automatically send the graphics processing work to the eGPU?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I'm looking for understanding how to say to a laptop which has an eGPU to be always using it, instead of using the integrated graphics. I've done some research and I've seen that you can configure in the OS the applications to use the eGPU, and even I found a script for do that but in a Mac.
The last thing that I found is that if in the device manager you disable the Integrated graphics, it will use the eGPU.
But how can I be really sure that this will happen ALWAYS? Because since a eGPU is connected via USB-C or Thunderbolt, is the OS really prepared to understand that if the integrated is disabled it will use that port to send the information, instead of just sending the info to the CPU and RAM?

Answer (score 0):

I use a Razor Core X eGPU. 
In the Thunderbolt 3 controller where it says "connected" click that and there should be an option for always connect. Also right click into the settings and make sure to set it to connect without user approval. I hope that helps!

This is the "connected" option:

[image]

This is how "settings" should look:
[image]